# Page not found (404), URL mapping in Django

Tags: python, django

I make up urlpatterns like below.

```
url(r'^sktag/(?P<st_char>\w+)/$', views.MW_Tag_Search.as_view(), name='tagSearch')
```

I typed url at chrome browser.

```
http://localhost:8000/common/sktag/Engineer(SW)
```

then I got the Page not found. refer to below

```
Using the URLconf defined in MW_Service.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. ^common/ ^sktag/(?P<st_char>\w+)/exclude/(?P<ex_tags>\w+[\+\w+]*)/$ [name='tagSearchV2']
2. ^common/ ^sktag/(?P<st_char>\w+)/$ [name='tagSearch']
...
The current URL, common/sktag/Engineer(SW), didn't match any of these.
```

I think the '(' or ')' character makes this problem, but I don't know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

That patterns you specified need a '/' at the end to match.

`http://localhost:8000/common/sktag/Engineer(SW)/`
should work.

Edit:

You also need to update your regular expression to handle the parentheses. Refer to the [Python Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)  documentation for more details.

Comment: It looks there are two problems. See above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your regex to accept parentheses. At the moment, `\w` only matches letters a-z, A-Z, digits 0-9 and underscores.

```
url(r'^sktag/(?P<st_char>[\w()]+)/$', views.MW_Tag_Search.as_view(), name='tagSearch')
```

As John mentions in his answer, you need to append a slash to the url as well, e.g.

```
http://localhost:8000/common/sktag/Engineer(SW)/
```